# ValueError: time data ' 1:00:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time, strptime

I'm trying to convert a string to 'datetime64[ns]' format. The hours are non-zero-padded, which I guess may cause the problem.

Example of data:

```
1    8:49:15
2    8:49:16
3    8:49:17
Name: time, dtype: object
```

The code that I use to convert the string to time:

```
dfp['time'] = pd.to_datetime(dfp['time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

I also tried:

```
time_tansformed = []

for t in dfp['time']:
    time_i = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M:%S")
    time_tansformed.append(time_i)
```

and I got the same error:

```
ValueError: time data ' 1:00:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)
```

I use Python 3.5 (Anaconda) on Win10.

How to convert it to time format?
Should I add 0 to pad the hours or is there a different way?

Comment: did you try `pd.to_datetime(dfp['time'])` (without specifying the format)?

Comment: Yes. It didn't work. It gave an error: 
 'OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 01:00:00'

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(dfp['time'])` worked for me for the strings with leading spaces without specifying format... I'm using Pandas 0.19.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a leading space in the string:

```
' 1:00:00'
```

Do this:

```
dfp['time'] = pd.to_datetime(dfp['time'].strip(), format='%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: That's a leading space, not a trailing one.

Comment: Problem solved. Removing the leading space fixed the problem.